# Android MediaPlayer Uri.parse problems (Api 15)

Tags: android, stream, nullpointerexception, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a book called Android Wireless Application Development 2nd edition 2009 (L.Darcey & S.Conder, published by Addison Wesley) as my literature for a course I'm currently doing in Android app development. In the third chapter of this book you use the MediaPlayer class to initiate a media player object to stream mp3 files to your app using to this method below.

```
public void playMusicFromWeb() {
    try {
        Uri file = Uri.parse("http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/6music/adamandjoe/adamandjoe_20111231-1430a.mp3");
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, file);
        mp.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Player failed", e);
    }
}
```

Happy days, this all works just fine in API 8 (which is what the book uses). However trying to use this method in a higher API, especially 15 which is (on writing) the latest API available I get a `NullPointerException` thrown. Debugging makes me none the wiser as the `file` variable seems to hold the string value fine, but it won't translate into a functional mp3 stream. I have tried various different approaches using `prepare(); prepareAsync(); setDataSource(); reset();` etc., however nothing seems to work. You'd think that my teachers would be able to help me out, but they apparently don't know what to do either.
I now assume that this way of streaming must be obsolete in higher API's than 8. I would be very grateful if someone could shine a light on how to stream an mp3 file in API 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as adding this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to the manifest file!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do more than that. [Here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/) is an example for doing what you want:

Answer (score 0):

1. The Header's `content-type` of the URL could be bad.
2. You could try this syntax:

   ```
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setDataSource(URL_OF_FILE);
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();
   ```

   See if the `NullPointerException` remains.
3. You could also view a more recent [tutorial on this particular subject](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in API 15 :( Thanks for your help anyway